# Ctrl-P on a page with alternating <tr> colors

Tags: html

I'm currently generating a form to print out using PHP, and I have my table row colors alternating back and forth between grey and white.

I need to print this page, but when I hit CTRL-P, the table row colors don't appear on the printed page. Is there any way to make it so it does?

Comment: That's likely a behaviour of your browser, rather than the web site. In Firefox I think there is a "print backgrounds" setting, for example. It might apply to this

Comment: try printing to a PDF first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended  up figuring it out. Adding !important in the CSS worked for me.

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color: #eee !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the default is to never print background images or colors (so the user doesn't end up wasting their ink by unnecessarily printing a full color background image on a site).

You can add CSS properties to try to override the default settings such as `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` or `background: #fefefe !important` in certain browsers, but the default will always be to not print backgrounds.